# Table width error with multirow and longtable with consecutive `multicolumn`s?

Tags: tables, longtable, multirow

I have this `longtable` table, where I want to locate two `multicolumn`s after each other. When I compile with the second `multicolumn` commented out, everything is fine (pic 1). But with two consecutive `multicolumn`s the width of the table is completely changed (pic 2). What's happening?

My question might be a duplicate of [Multicolumn width in longtable](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68235/multicolumn-width-in-longtable), but I don't see how the solution can be used in my problem...

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs,parskip}
\usepackage[text={9in,6in},showframe,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace,url,multirow,longtable,array}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{nolistsep}
\renewcommand\labelitemi{--}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\raggedright}p{\dimexpr#1\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{P{0.05} P{0.05} P{0.3} P{0.3} P{0.15} P{0.15}}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{Tema: } & \multicolumn{4}{l}{Geometri} \tabularnewline
    % \multicolumn{2}{l}{Kompetansemål i K06: } & \multicolumn{4}{l}{Some text} \tabularnewline
    \midrule
    Uke & Time & Læringsmål for timen & Arbeidsmetoder & Uformell vurdering & Kjerneord/ begreper \tabularnewline 
    \midrule
    \endfirsthead
    %
    \multicolumn{3}{c}%
    {{\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} -- fortsatt fra forrige side}} \tabularnewline
    \midrule Uke & Time & Læringsmål for timen & Arbeidsmetoder & Uformell vurdering & Kjerneord/begreper \tabularnewline \midrule
    \endhead
    %
    \midrule \multicolumn{3}{|r|}{{Fortsetter på neste side}} \tabularnewline \midrule
    \endfoot
    %
    \bottomrule
    \endlastfoot
    46 & 1 & Some stuff & Some more stuff & Utsjekk. & Katet, hypotenus, kvadrat
    \tabularnewline
    \bottomrule
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Producing

[image]

While without commenting out the second `multicolumn` the table is way outside the page borders:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your multicolumn switched the column type to `l` which forces the first two columns to be wide enough to take the text without line breaking, so they are wider than specified by your `P{0.05}` and the table overflows. You need to make the first two columns wider, or allow the text to break eg

```
    \multicolumn{2}{P{.1}}{Komp\-etan\-semål i K06: } & \multicolumn{4}{l}{Some text} \tabularnewline
```

Comment: Aha, thanks. Didn't catch that one.